# How to create a code box with HTML and React

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm doing my portfolio and I want to create a box like this:

[image]

A box that colorize the text with a programming language. Is there any library to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-highlight.js`:

```js
import Highlight from 'react-highlight.js';

<Highlight language={language}>
  {content}
</Highlight>
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/styles/railscasts.css'/>
```